# How to download file from website using web scraping in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to get a file using web scraping but I can't find "a" and "href". The link is [here](https://www.borsaistanbul.com/en/data/data/debt-securities-market-data/market-data). Maybe Data/File Paths above button can help but don't know how to use it. What should I do to achieve my aim?[image]

Comment: What are you using nerdakgul? Selenium? httr? rvest? something else? The button you are referring to is not a link. It is a javascript control that causes an http `POST` request to be sent. The request body is populated by javascript and is quite complex, so it's probably best to use RSelenium here.

Comment: RSelenium is my another option. I was just wondering if I could use a static package like rvest. You might be right @Allan

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is wondering how to run with RSelenium, they can run the following codes:

```
driver <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", port = 80L, chromever = "83.0.4103.39")
rmDr <- driver[["client"]]
rmDr$navigate("https://www.borsaistanbul.com/en/data/data/debt-securities-market-data/market-data")
download <- rmDr$findElement(using = "id", value = "TextContent_C001_lbtnIslemGorenTahvilVeBonolaraIliskinBilgiler")
download$clickElement()
```